# list the contents of a directory with os.path.isfile() and os.path.isdir() in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web.py, os.path

I need to create a web server in Python to list the contents of a directory (Files and Directories), but it turns out that only the files are being listed, in the test I am doing I am listing the "/ etc", but the problem is that it does not show the directories that exist inside / etc just several / etc and then it lists the files correctly, could someone help me ??

```
import web
import os

urls = (
'/(.*)', 'hello'
)
app = web.application(urls, globals())

class hello:
    def GET(self, path):

        path = '/etc/'+path
        lista = '<html> <body>'
        caminhos = [os.path.join(path, nome) for nome in os.listdir(path)]
        for nome in caminhos:
            lista = lista+path+'<br>'
        arquivos = [arq for arq in caminhos if os.path.isfile(arq)]
           for arq in arquivos:
               lista = lista+arq+ '<br>'
           lista = lista+'</body> </html>'
           return lista


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: `arquivos = [arq for arq in caminhos if os.path.isfile(arq)]`: that keeps only files. Is that your issue?

Comment: Please update your indents. If the second for-loop is supposed to be contained within the first one, then the `arquivos` list comprehension needs to be indented as well. If not, then unindent the second for-loop and the rest of your function.

Comment: I need the two to appear files and directories, as it will be a server for nevages in the directories and download the files